# Notification Delivery Issue: Seeking Assistance for Instant Call Functionality in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, agora.io

I'm encountering an issue with notification delivery in my application, specifically utilizing FCM. Notifications on my device are experiencing delays when the app is closed. Interestingly, notifications are promptly delivered when the app is running or in the background, even when the phone is locked. However, the problem arises when the app is completely closed, leading to delayed notification reception. This delay is particularly problematic for the call function within my app, as I need to display the call bar to the user instantly when the app is closed. Unfortunately, due to this notification delivery issue, I'm unable to achieve this functionality.

Could anyone provide assistance with resolving this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I've explored various approaches to handle notifications, including utilizing FCM and direct sending from the web. However, despite my efforts, I've found that neither approach has been successful. My preference is to continue using FCM for notification delivery.

Comment: didi you try setting the `priority` to `high` for the FCM

Comment: Yes. Have tried that as well.

Comment: please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to look at.